# How to use LINQ to retrieve a list from another entity with a specific number of items

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I can't explain It perfectly so I'm going to jump to the code

I have two entities on the EF

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use LINQ to get a list of categories, but each category with a specific number of books.

This is the way I'm doing It

```
List<Category> model = new List<Category>();

var categories = db.Categories.Include(b => b.Books);
foreach (Category cat in categories)
{
     Category newCat = new Category();
     newCat = cat;
     newCat.Books = cat.Books.Take(4).ToList();
     model.Add(newCat);
}
```

I'm trying to make the code shorter, can I avoid the foreach loop just using LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but how about like this? You'd have to specify each property in Categories individually, but it places it in one LINQ statement, and eliminates the `foreach` loop and multiple calls to `ToList`.

```
var model = db.Categories
              .Include(b => b.Books)
              .Select(c => new Category
                           {
                               Property1 = c.Property1,
                               Property2 = c.Property2,
                               ...,
                               Books = c.Books.Take(4)
                           })
              .ToList();
```

Assuming EF can generate a valid SQL query from this...

Comment: This worked, thanks! The only problem is, as the Category entity grows, I'll end up with even more code than before. Anyway, this is what I was looking for.